# how can i write elegant ping with powershell

Tags: powershell

I create script for check available resources:

```
$servers = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary"[String,String]"
$servers.Add("Server 1","127.0.0.1")
$servers.Add("Server 2","127.0.0.1")
$servers.Add("Server 3","127.0.0.1")

$virtuals = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary"[String,String]"
$virtuals.Add("VM 1","127.0.0.1")
$virtuals.Add("VM 2","127.0.0.1")
$virtuals.Add("VM 3","127.0.0.1")


Write-Output("`n")
Write-Output("Check availiable servers")


foreach ($key in $servers.GetEnumerator()){

    if ((Test-Connection $key.Value -Count 3 -Quiet)){        
        [pscustomobject]@{Server = $key.Key; Status = "Availiable"}
    }else{
    [pscustomobject]@{Server = $key.Key; Status = "Not availiable"}
    }
}
Remove-Variable -Name [pscustomobject]
Write-Output("`n")
Write-Output("Check availiable virtuals")
Write-Output("`n")

foreach ($key in $virtuals.GetEnumerator()){

    if ((Test-Connection $key.Value -Count 3 -Quiet)){
        [pscustomobject]@{VM = $key.Key; Status = "Availiable"}
        
    }else{
        [pscustomobject]@{VM = $key.Key; Status = "Not availiable"}
    }
}
```

[image]

If I change the title, then the output is in the following table without the first column. And I can't find how I can print the title in every new cycle? My ultimate goal is to have a header for each new loop and color-coded available and unavailable addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'elegant' you mean outputting a line in the table in some color, depending on availability, use something like this:

```
$servers = [ordered]@{
    "Server 1" = "127.0.0.1"
    "Server 2" = "127.0.0.1"
    "Server 3" = "127.0.0.1"
}

$virtuals = [ordered]@{
    "VM 1" = "127.0.0.1"
    "VM 2" = "127.0.0.1"
    "VM 3" = "127.0.0.1"
}


Write-Host "Check available servers" -ForegroundColor Cyan

$svr = foreach ($key in $servers.GetEnumerator()){
    if ((Test-Connection $key.Value -Count 3 -Quiet)){        
        [pscustomobject]@{Server = $key.Key; Status = "Available"}
    }
    else{
        [pscustomobject]@{Server = $key.Key; Status = "Not available"}
    }
}
# output this as colored table
$svr | Format-Table | Out-String -Stream | ForEach-Object {
    $color = if ($_ -match 'Not available') { 'Red' } else { 'Green' }
    Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor $color
}

Write-Host

# now do the same for the VMs
Write-Host "Check available virtuals" -ForegroundColor Cyan

$vms = foreach ($key in $virtuals.GetEnumerator()){
    if ((Test-Connection $key.Value -Count 3 -Quiet)){
        [pscustomobject]@{VM = $key.Key; Status = "Available"}
    }
    else{
        [pscustomobject]@{VM = $key.Key; Status = "Not available"}
    }
}

# output this as colored table
$vms | Format-Table | Out-String -Stream | ForEach-Object {
    $color = if ($_ -match 'Not available') { 'Red' } else { 'Green' }
    Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor $color
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As PowerShell has already added the titles to the tops of the columns from the previous item, it doesn't add them again. Part of its way to reduce repetition or something probably.

You could maybe do an output using `Write-Host` and then you can format to your hearts content.

```
Write-Host "Servers" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-Host "Virtuals" -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

You could also do something like...

```
if ($status -eq "Available") {
    $color = "Green"
} else {
    $color = "Red"
}
```

Then when you come to write your results you could do...

```
Write-Host "Server Name" -ForegroundColor $color
```

Hope that makes sense, I can write something out fully if you need.

Comment: Thanks. how can i align the output? http://prntscr.com/1292kgh

Comment: In this method there is no real way to tidy them up. You could work out the length of the server names and find the longest length one. Then take the length of a given server name, subtract it from the longest and suffix the number of space characters to the end of it before it is presented. Then they'd all "appear" the same length and then line up. :)